# Kendo UI HierarchicalDataSource schema not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have a kendo tree which i am trying to bind it to a local json arrray.

Trying to map my json object properties to what treeView expects is not working.

The value of the "text" property is the function definition (`function (item){ return item.Text; }`) The function itself doesn't gets evaluated

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LmYC4/)

Html:

```
<div id="tree"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var data = [
    {
       "Text": "Some dummy text"
    }
];

var inlineDefault = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    data: data,
    schema: {
        model: {
            text: function(item){
                return item.Text;
            }
        }
    }
});

$("#tree").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: inlineDefault
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using projection in the data source, use the [TreeView dataTextField](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#configuration-dataTextField) to define where your data is located:

```
var data = [
    {
       "Text": "Some dummy text"
    }
];

var inlineDefault = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    data: data
});

$("#tree").kendoTreeView({
    dataTextField: "Text",
    dataSource: inlineDefault
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining a schema model in this way is not supported - see the options [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/model#methods-Model.define),the additional field for hierarchical data sources [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/hierarchicaldatasource#configuration-schema.model.hasChildren) and an example on how to create a tree view [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/treeview/overview#initialize-and-bind-the-treeview).